How does one prove that the electric field is conservative when it is not defined on simply-connected regions?
I apologize for the ignorance and the rough English in advance, I have an issue understanding how to match both what happens in physics and what I am seeing in calculus.
In my calculus class we learned that if a vector field be defined on an open simply-connected region and the partial derivatives of its components are continuous and equal over said region, then the field is conservative. This I also then learned is not necessary for a field to be conservative, as in, it may not be defined on a simply connected region and still be conservative, but in general I was told it is simpler to prove it to be conservative if we can apply the theorem.
I don't quite understand however, how can one prove that a vector field, such as the electric field created by a charged particle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , is conservative when by definition it is not defined for that particular point in space (or here in the plane). I know from physics that it is conservative but I don't understand how one can prove that to be the case, since the other theorem I learned to prove that a field is conservative requires the curl of the field to be zero, but it also said that it is true so long as the field is defined on a simply-connected region.
I have the same issue if I take an electric field created in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by an infinitely large rod of charged conducting material, which is the case where the field would not be defined on a line in space.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology

Definition of a potential field. A conservative field is a field so that the line integral
$$\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} \ ,$$
is independent on the path but only depends on its extreme points.
Conservative fields with non-simply-connected domains. You just need to test that the work integral on A closed line embracing the hole equals zero. If it's zero on a closed line is zero on all the closed lines around the same singularity/hole (not hard to prove, exploiting the regularity of the field).
The condition $\nabla \times \mathbf{e} = \mathbf{0}$ (this is the condition "on the partial derivatives" you need to get a conservative field, not the one you mentioned in your question) in the domain does the rest.
As an example, you can evaluate the integral on a circle centered in the point charge
$$\oint_\gamma \mathbf{e} \cdot  \mathbf{\hat{t}} = R \int_{\theta= 0}^{2\pi} \mathbf{e} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 0 \ ,$$
since $\mathbf{e} = e(\mathbf{r}) \, \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{\hat{t}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$.

Ahh okay I think I got a better idea now. So if I were to have a vector field such as $ \vec{F}(x;y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\vec{i} + \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\vec{j}$ then in order to prove that it is conservative even though I cannot use the aforementioned theorem, one would have to find some way of showcasing that any line integral, without passing through the origin, is independent of path and then the point where F is undefined is not really something that interferes with the definition of conservative fields right?

I don't know about proving it mathematically, but intuitively, you can always imagine that there are no real point charges or infinitely thin rods. You can assume they are super small, but the charge density and the electric field are always finite and well defined. Now take the limit as the charge density becomes infinite when the little charged sphere becomes a  singular point. I am pretty sure the limit is well behaved and exists, at least if your path doesn't go through the point charge. Remember that the electric field outside a spherically symmetric charge distribution is the same outside the charge distribution, so if it is conservative for a small charged sphere, it should also be for a point charge if you avoid the charge itself.
